# Deploying a Flask app on a VPS

Tags: python, flask

I'm following the directions here to create my first flask app:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

I'm on a VPS and I'm trying to get the first example, the hello world app, to display in a webpage.

I followed the directions on "Externally Visible Server" and get this on the command line:

```
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

But I'm not sure what else I need to tie in to actually make this viewable?  Should my VPS IP go in, instead of 0.0.0.0?

Comment: what happens when you go to http://public_ip_of_vps:5000?

Comment: Oh.  That was easy.  Thanks John.

Comment: Just a heads up: 0.0.0.0 generally means "bind to all of my external IP addresses". 127.0.0.1 would mean "bind only to my loopback". And any other IP behaves the way you'd think.

Comment: That being said, Flask's integrated webserver is meant for testing only and shouldn't be used in production. If you plan to use your app in production, refer to the related documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 allows access through all IPs and hostnames that point to any one of the IPs available on your VPS.

So, you should be able to visit your app via `any_ip_of_your_vps:5000`